# Close questions: no number next to the option

Tags: support, review, close-dialog

I've noticed this problem several times, I'm not sure if it's a bug though.

**When I review the close votes, sometimes when I click the close button I can't see what the original closer has chosen as an option.**

Most of the time you see a blue square with the number of close votes next to the option but sometimes there's nothing.

The only way I can see why the question is being closed is by clicking the `(more)` next to `This question has been flagged as:`

See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: You don't see a number if the question was flagged by a user without close vote privileges because the flag isn't a close vote, it only puts the question into the review queue.

Comment: @rene so that means people under 15 reps ?

Comment: No, under 3000 on regular sites @RaphPetrini

Comment: No, everyone under close vote privileges, which is 3K on normal sites and 400/1500? on beta sites

Comment: @rene 1/500 on private/public beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post in question has been **flagged**, not **voted to close**. Only the latter will add a number next to the close reason.

I do agree this would be a useful feature to have, even if someone flagged it, it is useful information to the review. So why not add another box (or a way to integrate it in the current box) for the times it was flagged.

Comment: I disagree that it would be useful to add. The flag is raised by a user we don't trust yet to cast close votes. Don't pretend the flag is legit, review the question as if you have no prior knowledge. You're the first to judge the possible closure which could lead to deletion of value, make sure you do it right.

Comment: You should do that no matter if it has been flagged or voted to close

Comment: True, but as the first and last close voter you have greater responsibilities in my opinion.

Comment: If you as a second review blindly follow the first, you are doing something wrong. Every review has to be taken on its own.

Comment: Yes, I don't disagree with that, reviewing is a great responsibility, the first and last one should carry even more weight on your already careful consideration.

Comment: Worth to mention that duplicate flags are showing the number. To prove, go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826577/how-to-change-forecolor-of-title-bar) now, open the close dialog and choose Duplicate - there is a number even though it's only a flag, not actual close vote.

Comment: Indeed, but only after you hit the 'Duplicate' button @sha

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh8P3.png

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Updated comment @sha

Comment: Still, different behavior than the off topic. Or not? I don't remember if it's showing the number in the "sub menu" close reasons.

Comment: Not sure @Sha. We have to find someone with reputation low enough to flag :)

Comment: @Pat I have my sock, but it got only 1 rep on SO. :/